# 500 error with Twilio C# REST Api on Azure Staging

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, twilio

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient(ConstantKeys.AccountSid,ConstantKeys.AuthToken); // instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client

var messageCallBack = client.SendMessage(ConstantKeys.SmsEnabledTwilioNumber, mobileNumber, smsMessage);
```

Above code snippet is working fine on localhost but when we publish and try to use the same on live site we are getting a 500 error.We are using windows azure for hosting our website.It doesn't reach the first line of the above code on production.Can you tell me why ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note :I have checked the dlls on published version.It's having below dlls.
Twilio.Api.dll and RestSharp.dll

Site link : [The Twilio C# Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install)

Comment: have you tried putting logs in between those lines and checking if they are generated ?

Comment: @Shekhar Yes,I have put a log and it's not reaching the 'TwilioRestClient()' section on the production.That is first line.But local host it's working fine.

Comment: If the method is not being hit, the content of the method could have little to do with it in my opinion. I would investigate the place from where the call is being made. Just to cover all bases you could also try changing the content of the method and see how it behaves

Comment: @Shekhar Actually this same method is working fine on local host with the same testing mobile numbers.But on production it's hanged on first line and gives 500 internal server error ?

Comment: hmm, could it be that the accountsid, authtoken are for development use and you need prod versions of them, ?

Comment: @Shekhar Nope.Keys are common for the dev and prod.

Comment: Which feature of Azure are you using to host your site?  Azure websites, a Web Role in Cloud Services or something else?

Comment: @DevinRader This is a Web Role...

Comment: @DevinRader I have added Twilio dlls on separate class library project called BLL. That class library (BLL) is referenced from the asp.net mvc web role project.This setup is woking fine when I run it on local host.But when I host it on azure as a web role,it's not working and gives 500 error.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed error log generated by the 500 internal server error?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is a known issue with the Twilio MVC helper library when deployed to a web role that prevents the library from finding the correct ASP.NET MVC dependency.

Right now the work around is to grab the source of the library, update that dependency to ASP.NET MVC 3 or newer and recompile.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get exactly what you said.Can I have more info about it or the steps ? I'm using .Net 4.5 (MVC 4).Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have installed Twilio dependencies by using Nuget package.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by "update that dependency to ASP.NET MVC 3 or newer and recompile" ? Which dependencies are you referring ?

Comment: Please tell me, don't you have any answer for my question above ?

Comment: After latest nuget update where now I have different issue.Please check that.Thanks in advance.https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/157

Comment: I have opened an issue on Github. Please check that. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/158